# How do I run a java class, using Intellij, that needs configuration files from another project/module?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm trying to replicate in Intellij something easily done in Eclipse.

I want to run this Main class from the mainProject (nevermind the errors due to the use of fictional names):

[image: eclipse run java class]

Now, the problem is I need to be able to import a configuration folder from another project, in order to run the Main class. This is easy in Eclipse:

[image]

But I don't know how to do this is Intellij. Ideas?

Comment: Hmm... Try "Import module".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually why I despise the Eclipse workspace. It lets developers cheat and use another project's source as a dependency of another project. This is a problem because this isn't how it works outside of the IDE.

What you need to do is create a jar of classes you depend on, then include that jar as a dependency of the project that depends on them. If you use dependency management and have a local repository (like nexus or artifactory) you can publish your jar to your local repository and then in your other project just include it in your pom.xml if you are using Maven or build.gradle if you are using Gradle.

If you are instead including libraries in your source folder, copy the jar to your project, then right click on the jar in IntelliJ and select "Add as Library...". You can also add a dependency through File->Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies tab. Add as Library is a shortcut to adding a library here and the dependency shows up here if you use Add as Library.

IntelliJ does let you import a module from another project, but again this is cheating because it will just confuse you down the road because it will only work from within the IDE, not running as a standalone application. (File->Project Structure->Modules->Plus (+) Sign->Import Module)

Comment: Agreed, you should NOT rely on Eclipse's custom method of allowing inter-project dependencies.  It is not portable.  You should be leveraging a proper module system, for example, Maven, and import multiple maven modules into your IntelliJ Project (which, would also work with Eclipse)